# Guardians of the Flame ur-answer unaccepted

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, story-identification, deleted-comments

Generally, our policy for closing story-id dupes is that only accepted answers can be marked as dupes, or can be marked as the answer that the others are dupes of. The various *Guardians of the Flame* answers indicate [Book about RPG players who get pulled into their game](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28017/book-about-rpg-players-who-get-pulled-into-their-game/28018#28018) as the answer they are dupes of, but I don't see anywhere that it was accepted. Before I went out and "fixed" the situation, I wanted to see if maybe there's a deleted acceptance comment I can't see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no deleted answers on this thread, nor any deleted comments on the question or answer.

Fortunately, as a gold tag badge holder you have the power to redirect duplicate targets without reopening and reclosing the duplicate questions.

Comment: Alright. I think all of the changes are made. I just didn't want to do it until I was certain there wasn't a good reason they were linking to the other answer. Inertia, I guess.

Comment: As a side note, I incorrectly changed the Dupe sources of one question, but changed them back.